# Recording video on Android using JavaCV (Updated 2014 02 17)

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, javacv

I'm trying to record a video in Android using the JavaCV lib.
I need to record the video in 640x360.

I have installed everything as described in README.txt file and I followed the example as below:
https://code.google.com/p/javacv/source/browse/samples/RecordActivity.java
In this example, the video size is this:
private int imageWidth = 320;
private int imageHeight = 240;

In my case, I need to record a video in 640x360 H.264.

(UPDATE) I have reverted my code and kept exactly like in the example, just changing imageWidth and imageHeight to 640x360.
Now I'm getting the video like this image:
http://bergmann.net.br/img/screenshot_video_error.png

Here is my code:

```
import static com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.IPL_DEPTH_8U;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ShortBuffer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback;
import android.media.AudioFormat;
import android.media.AudioRecord;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.autosonvideo.helpers.Helpers;
import com.autosonvideo.logic.CameraHelpers;
import com.googlecode.javacv.FFmpegFrameRecorder;
import com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.IplImage;

public class FFmpegRecordActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private final static String CLASS_LABEL = "RecordActivity";
    private final static String LOG_TAG = CLASS_LABEL;

    private PowerManager.WakeLock mWakeLock;

    private String ffmpeg_link;

    long startTime = 0;
    boolean recording = false;

    private volatile FFmpegFrameRecorder recorder;

    private boolean isPreviewOn = false;

    private int sampleAudioRateInHz = 44100;
    private int imageWidth = 640;
    private int imageHeight = 480;

    private int finalImageWidth = 640;
    private int finalImageHeight = 360;

    private int frameRate = 30;

    /* audio data getting thread */
    private AudioRecord audioRecord;
    private AudioRecordRunnable audioRecordRunnable;
    private Thread audioThread;
    volatile boolean runAudioThread = true;

    /* video data getting thread */
    private Camera cameraDevice;
    private CameraView cameraView;

    private IplImage yuvIplimage = null;

    /* layout setting */
    private final int bg_screen_bx = 232;
    private final int bg_screen_by = 128;
    private final int bg_screen_width = 700;
    private final int bg_screen_height = 500;
    private final int bg_width = 1123;
    private final int bg_height = 715;
    private final int live_width = 1280;
    private final int live_height = 960;
    private int screenWidth, screenHeight;
    private Button btnRecorderControl;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK,
                CLASS_LABEL);
        mWakeLock.acquire();

        initLayout();
        initRecorder();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (mWakeLock == null) {
            PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
            mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK,
                    CLASS_LABEL);
            mWakeLock.acquire();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (mWakeLock != null) {
            mWakeLock.release();
            mWakeLock = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        recording = false;

        if (cameraView != null) {
            cameraView.stopPreview();
            cameraDevice.release();
            cameraDevice = null;
        }

        if (mWakeLock != null) {
            mWakeLock.release();
            mWakeLock = null;
        }
    }

    private void initLayout() {

        /* get size of screen */
        Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE))
                .getDefaultDisplay();
        screenWidth = display.getWidth();
        screenHeight = display.getHeight();
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParam = null;
        LayoutInflater myInflate = null;
        myInflate = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        RelativeLayout topLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        setContentView(topLayout);
        LinearLayout preViewLayout = (LinearLayout) myInflate.inflate(
                R.layout.main, null);
        layoutParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(screenWidth, screenHeight);
        topLayout.addView(preViewLayout, layoutParam);

        /* add control button: start and stop */
        btnRecorderControl = (Button) findViewById(R.id.recorder_control);
        btnRecorderControl.setText("Start");
        btnRecorderControl.setOnClickListener(this);

        /* add camera view */
        int display_width_d = (int) (1.0 * bg_screen_width * screenWidth / bg_width);
        int display_height_d = (int) (1.0 * bg_screen_height * screenHeight / bg_height);
        int prev_rw, prev_rh;
        if (1.0 * display_width_d / display_height_d > 1.0 * live_width
                / live_height) {
            prev_rh = display_height_d;
            prev_rw = (int) (1.0 * display_height_d * live_width / live_height);
        } else {
            prev_rw = display_width_d;
            prev_rh = (int) (1.0 * display_width_d * live_height / live_width);
        }
        layoutParam = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(prev_rw, prev_rh);
        layoutParam.topMargin = (int) (1.0 * bg_screen_by * screenHeight / bg_height);
        layoutParam.leftMargin = (int) (1.0 * bg_screen_bx * screenWidth / bg_width);

        cameraDevice = Camera.open();
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "cameara open");
        cameraView = new CameraView(this, cameraDevice);
        topLayout.addView(cameraView, layoutParam);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "cameara preview start: OK");
    }

    // ---------------------------------------
    // initialize ffmpeg_recorder
    // ---------------------------------------
    private void initRecorder() {

        Log.w(LOG_TAG, "init recorder");

        if (yuvIplimage == null) {
            yuvIplimage = IplImage.create(finalImageWidth, finalImageHeight,
                    IPL_DEPTH_8U, 2);
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "create yuvIplimage");
        }

        ffmpeg_link = CameraHelpers.getOutputMediaFile(
                CameraHelpers.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO).toString();

        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "ffmpeg_url: " + ffmpeg_link);
        recorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder(ffmpeg_link, finalImageWidth,
                finalImageHeight, 1);
        recorder.setFormat("mp4");
        recorder.setSampleRate(sampleAudioRateInHz);
        // Set in the surface changed method
        recorder.setFrameRate(frameRate);

        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "recorder initialize success");

        audioRecordRunnable = new AudioRecordRunnable();
        audioThread = new Thread(audioRecordRunnable);
    }

    public void startRecording() {

        try {
            recorder.start();
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            recording = true;
            audioThread.start();

        } catch (FFmpegFrameRecorder.Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void stopRecording() {

        runAudioThread = false;

        if (recorder != null && recording) {
            recording = false;
            Log.v(LOG_TAG,
                    "Finishing recording, calling stop and release on recorder");
            try {
                recorder.stop();
                recorder.release();
            } catch (FFmpegFrameRecorder.Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            recorder = null;

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            if (recording) {
                stopRecording();
            }

            finish();

            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    // ---------------------------------------------
    // audio thread, gets and encodes audio data
    // ---------------------------------------------
    class AudioRecordRunnable implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            android.os.Process
                    .setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_AUDIO);

            // Audio
            int bufferSize;
            short[] audioData;
            int bufferReadResult;

            bufferSize = AudioRecord
                    .getMinBufferSize(sampleAudioRateInHz,
                            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
            audioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
                    sampleAudioRateInHz, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, bufferSize);

            audioData = new short[bufferSize];

            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "audioRecord.startRecording()");
            audioRecord.startRecording();

            /* ffmpeg_audio encoding loop */
            while (runAudioThread) {
                // Log.v(LOG_TAG,"recording? " + recording);
                bufferReadResult = audioRecord.read(audioData, 0,
                        audioData.length);
                if (bufferReadResult > 0) {
                    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "bufferReadResult: " + bufferReadResult);
                    // If "recording" isn't true when start this thread, it
                    // never get's set according to this if statement...!!!
                    // Why? Good question...
                    if (recording) {
                        try {
                            recorder.record(ShortBuffer.wrap(audioData, 0,
                                    bufferReadResult));
                            // Log.v(LOG_TAG,"recording " + 1024*i + " to " +
                            // 1024*i+1024);
                        } catch (FFmpegFrameRecorder.Exception e) {
                            Log.v(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "AudioThread Finished, release audioRecord");

            /* encoding finish, release recorder */
            if (audioRecord != null) {
                audioRecord.stop();
                audioRecord.release();
                audioRecord = null;
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "audioRecord released");
            }
        }
    }

    // ---------------------------------------------
    // camera thread, gets and encodes video data
    // ---------------------------------------------
    class CameraView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback,
            PreviewCallback {

        private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
        private Camera mCamera;

        public CameraView(Context context, Camera camera) {
            super(context);
            Log.w("camera", "camera view");
            mCamera = camera;
            mHolder = getHolder();
            mHolder.addCallback(CameraView.this);
            mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
            mCamera.setPreviewCallback(CameraView.this);
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            try {
                stopPreview();
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            } catch (IOException exception) {
                mCamera.release();
                mCamera = null;
            }
        }

        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
                int height) {
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Setting imageWidth: " + imageWidth
                    + " imageHeight: " + imageHeight + " frameRate: "
                    + frameRate);
            Camera.Parameters camParams = mCamera.getParameters();
            camParams.setPreviewSize(imageWidth, imageHeight);

            Log.v(LOG_TAG,
                    "Preview Framerate: " + camParams.getPreviewFrameRate());

            camParams.setPreviewFrameRate(frameRate);
            mCamera.setParameters(camParams);
            startPreview();
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            try {
                mHolder.addCallback(null);
                mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                // The camera has probably just been released, ignore.
            }
        }

        public void startPreview() {
            if (!isPreviewOn && mCamera != null) {
                isPreviewOn = true;
                mCamera.startPreview();
            }
        }

        public void stopPreview() {
            if (isPreviewOn && mCamera != null) {
                isPreviewOn = false;
                mCamera.stopPreview();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            /* get video data */
            if (yuvIplimage != null && recording) {
                // yuvIplimage.getByteBuffer().put(data);

                final int startY = 640 * (480 - 360) / 2;
                final int lenY = 640 * 360;
                yuvIplimage.getByteBuffer().put(data, startY, lenY);
                final int startVU = 640 * 480 + 320 * 2 * (240 - 180) / 2;
                final int lenVU = 320 * 180 * 2;
                yuvIplimage.getByteBuffer().put(data, startVU, lenVU);

                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Writing Frame");
                try {
                    long t = 1000 * (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
                    if (t > recorder.getTimestamp()) {
                        recorder.setTimestamp(t);
                    }
                    recorder.record(yuvIplimage);
                } catch (FFmpegFrameRecorder.Exception e) {
                    Log.v(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (!recording) {
            startRecording();
            Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Start Button Pushed");
            btnRecorderControl.setText("Stop");
        } else {
            // This will trigger the audio recording loop to stop and then set
            // isRecorderStart = false;
            stopRecording();
            Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Stop Button Pushed");
            btnRecorderControl.setText("Start");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your device support 640x360 recording?Check it with `Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();

    List<Size> sizeList = params.getSupportedVideoSizes();`

Comment: It doesn't, that's the case. I have tried to use ffmpeg to convert my video, after recorded in a supported resolution, but it too slow and takes a long time to get done. I don't understand why it is so fast in iOS. Anyway, I gave up that resolution and now I'm using just a supported one. Thanks

Comment: Probably, iOS camera does support this resolution natively.

Comment: @Apoorv How can i capture square video in portrait mode using `FFmpeg`. like Instagram does. right now I can't make it portrait.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your camera, most likely, can provide 640x480 preview frames. The fix would be to clip this frame before it is recorded, like this:

```
@Override
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    /* get video data */
    if (yuvIplimage != null && recording) {
        ByteBuffer bb = yuvIplimage.getByteBuffer(); // resets the buffer
        final int startY = imageWidth*(imageHeight-finalImageHeight)/2;
        final int lenY = imageWidth*finalImageHeight;
        bb.put(data, startY, lenY);
        final int startVU = imageWidth*imageHeight + imageWidth*(imageHeight-finalImageHeight)/4;
        final int lenVU = imageWidth* finalImageHeight/2;
        bb.put(data, startVU, lenVU);

//      Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Writing Frame");
        try {
            long t = 1000 * (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
            if (t > recorder.getTimestamp()) {
                recorder.setTimestamp(t);
             }
             recorder.record(yuvIplimage);
        } catch (FFmpegFrameRecorder.Exception e) {
             Log.e(LOG_TAG, "problem with recorder():", e);
        }
    }
}
```

The preview frame has semi-planar YVU format: 640x480 luminance (Y) bytes, followed by 320x240 pairs of chroma (V and U) bytes. We copy to `yuvIpImage` first the relevant Y, and after that - relevant VU pairs. Note that it is easy and fast because the width you want is same as the native width.

Your camera and camera view should be initialized for 640x480, and recorder - to 640x360. Note that the efficient cropping is only possible when **imageWidth==finalImageWidth**.

**FIX** it happens so that **IplImage.getByteBuffer()** resets the buffer, therefore the fix is to use a temporary **bb** object.

Note that you will probably want to overlay the preview with a frame that will "hide" margins that you crop this way: our manipulations only change the recorded frames, not the `CameraView`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But, if I change imageWidth = 320; imageHeight = 240; to 640 x 480, I get a video with green frames.

Comment: Does your camera support 640x480 preview? And please share your code that gives green frames.

Comment: Did you change the `initRecorder()` method? You should initialize both `yuvIplimage` and `recorder` to `640x360`.

Comment: I changed the resolution by changing the values in the vars imageWidth and imageHeight. So it changed the initialization of yuvIplimage and recorder. I've tried many things without success. I always get a video with mixed colors.

Comment: there are two uses of imageHeight in your code. These must be decoupled to use my cropping solution.

Comment: I changed the onPreviewFrame method to the original one and it worked fine in 640x480. I think there is something wrong in the calcs of the clip.

Comment: I've put another variable for that and kept imageHeight to 480. Only yuvIplimage and recorder is know set to 360, but same result. I'm getting a green video.

Comment: No, it works fine here. Please check that you use 640x360 in ` initRecorder()` method. Maybe you can update your post so that I can check what could be wrong

Comment: Any idea about why I get a green video?

Comment: I didn't know that **IplImage.getByteBuffer()** resets the buffer, therefore it should only be used once per frame. The fix is to use a temporary **bb** object.

Comment: @Alex Cohn Could you please check this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33669457/issue-in-recording-video-with-resolution-not-natively-supported-in-android ?I am trying to imeplement a video recorder and struck at processing frames to get video in desired resolution (ie, 480*480)

Answer (score 1):

@Fabio Seeing that your code is from this [Open Source Android Touch-To-Record library](https://github.com/sourab-sharma/TouchToRecord) and I too have used it. Here is my modified version of the onPreviewFrame method, inside CameraPreview class, to take transpose and resize a captured frame, as the captured video played sideways (app was locked to portrait) and with **greenish output**.

I defined "yuvIplImage" as following in my setCameraParams() method.

```
IplImage yuvIplImage = IplImage.create(mPreviewSize.height, mPreviewSize.width, opencv_core.IPL_DEPTH_8U, 2);
```

Also initialize your videoRecorder object as following, giving width as height and vice versa.

```
//call initVideoRecorder() method like this to initialize videoRecorder object of FFmpegFrameRecorder class.
initVideoRecorder(strVideoPath, mPreview.getPreviewSize().height, mPreview.getPreviewSize().width, recorderParameters);

//method implementation
public void initVideoRecorder(String videoPath, int width, int height, RecorderParameters recorderParameters)
{
    Log.e(TAG, "initVideoRecorder");

    videoRecorder = new FFmpegFrameRecorder(videoPath, width, height, 1);
    videoRecorder.setFormat(recorderParameters.getVideoOutputFormat());
    videoRecorder.setSampleRate(recorderParameters.getAudioSamplingRate());
    videoRecorder.setFrameRate(recorderParameters.getVideoFrameRate());
    videoRecorder.setVideoCodec(recorderParameters.getVideoCodec());
    videoRecorder.setVideoQuality(recorderParameters.getVideoQuality());
    videoRecorder.setAudioQuality(recorderParameters.getVideoQuality());
    videoRecorder.setAudioCodec(recorderParameters.getAudioCodec());
    videoRecorder.setVideoBitrate(1000000);
    videoRecorder.setAudioBitrate(64000);
}
```

This is my onPreviewFrame() method:

```
@Override
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera)
{

    long frameTimeStamp = 0L;

    if(FragmentCamera.mAudioTimestamp == 0L && FragmentCamera.firstTime > 0L)
    {
        frameTimeStamp = 1000L * (System.currentTimeMillis() - FragmentCamera.firstTime);
    }
    else if(FragmentCamera.mLastAudioTimestamp == FragmentCamera.mAudioTimestamp)
    {
        frameTimeStamp = FragmentCamera.mAudioTimestamp + FragmentCamera.frameTime;
    }
    else
    {
        long l2 = (System.nanoTime() - FragmentCamera.mAudioTimeRecorded) / 1000L;
        frameTimeStamp = l2 + FragmentCamera.mAudioTimestamp;
        FragmentCamera.mLastAudioTimestamp = FragmentCamera.mAudioTimestamp;
    }

    synchronized(FragmentCamera.mVideoRecordLock)
    {
        if(FragmentCamera.recording && FragmentCamera.rec && lastSavedframe != null && lastSavedframe.getFrameBytesData() != null && yuvIplImage != null)
        {
            FragmentCamera.mVideoTimestamp += FragmentCamera.frameTime;

            if(lastSavedframe.getTimeStamp() > FragmentCamera.mVideoTimestamp)
            {
                FragmentCamera.mVideoTimestamp = lastSavedframe.getTimeStamp();
            }

            try
            {
                yuvIplImage.getByteBuffer().put(lastSavedframe.getFrameBytesData());

                IplImage bgrImage = IplImage.create(mPreviewSize.width, mPreviewSize.height, opencv_core.IPL_DEPTH_8U, 4);// In my case, mPreviewSize.width = 1280 and mPreviewSize.height = 720
                IplImage transposed = IplImage.create(mPreviewSize.height, mPreviewSize.width, yuvIplImage.depth(), 4);
                IplImage squared = IplImage.create(mPreviewSize.height, mPreviewSize.height, yuvIplImage.depth(), 4);

                int[] _temp = new int[mPreviewSize.width * mPreviewSize.height];

                Util.YUV_NV21_TO_BGR(_temp, data, mPreviewSize.width,  mPreviewSize.height);

                bgrImage.getIntBuffer().put(_temp);

                opencv_core.cvTranspose(bgrImage, transposed);
                opencv_core.cvFlip(transposed, transposed, 1);

                opencv_core.cvSetImageROI(transposed, opencv_core.cvRect(0, 0, mPreviewSize.height, mPreviewSize.height));
                opencv_core.cvCopy(transposed, squared, null);
                opencv_core.cvResetImageROI(transposed);

                videoRecorder.setTimestamp(lastSavedframe.getTimeStamp());
                videoRecorder.record(squared);
            }
            catch(com.googlecode.javacv.FrameRecorder.Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        lastSavedframe = new SavedFrames(data, frameTimeStamp);
    }
}
```

This code uses a method "**YUV_NV21_TO_BGR**", which I found from this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/javacv/zo_pZPgDRNA)

Basically this method is used to resolve, which I call as, **"The Green Devil problem on Android"**, just like yours. I was having the same issue and wasted almost 3-4 days. Before adding "YUV_NV21_TO_BGR" method when I just took transpose of YuvIplImage, more importantly a combination of transpose, flip (with or without resizing), there was **greenish output** in resulting video. This "YUV_NV21_TO_BGR" method saved the day. Thanks to @David Han from above google groups thread.

Comment: I try your code work perfectly but i don't known why i fill little but slow frames or may be drop of frame  in my out put video file which is mp4.

Answer (score 0):

Use [this](https://github.com/qdrzwd/VideoRecorder) link to resolve the issue . The issue is with rotation of image.The YUV Image handling has been done.